# Extract several of jar in one command

Tags: java, unix, jar, terminal, zip

I have folders with lots (20) of jar files. Is there a way to extract all those jars in one command in the terminal instead doing it one by one? 
I'm using a MAC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution.-  Get all the jars and extract it

```
find ./ -name "*.jar" -exec jar -xf {} \;
```

Comment: Hi , thanks. im getting and error , should I be in the root folder in the cli ?

Comment: No need. You have to be in same folder, where jars are available. Also what error you are getting?

Comment: im in the terminal in the folder which contain the list of jars and getting this error java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Comment: Looks like you dont have write permission in the folder. Make sure you have write permissions

Comment: I use sudo without sucess ,any other idea how to achive rights? btw the error says not found ...

Comment: when I try `find ./ -name *.jar -exec jar -xf {} \;` I got error find: asm-5.0.4.jar: unknown primary or operator

Comment: Try to copy that to a different directory and try to extract the jar? is single jar extract working fine?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this from the folder in which all your jars are -

```
jar {ctxu}[vfm0Mi] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [-C dir]
```

Options:

```
-c  create new archive

-t  list table of contents for archive

-x  extract named (or all) files from archive

-u  update existing archive

-v  generate verbose output on standard output

-f  specify archive file name

-m  include manifest information from specified manifest file

-0  store only; use no ZIP compression

-M  do not create a manifest file for the entries

-i  generate index information for the specified jar files

-C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
```

refer the documentation for explaination - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

you may user ***.jar** in place of **jar-file** to extract all

This should extract in same location where the jars are present.

```
 jar xvf *.jar
```

Comment: what should I put in  [archived-file(s)] ?

Comment: Its an optional parameter.

Documentation states - archived-file(s) is an optional argument consisting of a space-separated list of the files to be extracted from the archive. If this argument is not present, the Jar tool will extract all the files in the archive.

Comment: so what should I use? I try with `jar xf "*.jar"` without sucess

Comment: try noting happen, didnt recive any error and the jar's was not extracted...any other idea?

Comment: ""jar xf *.jar .""  Try this 


.(dot) Represents the current folder so may be they wld be extracted in d same folder

Comment: I want to do it in the same folder , how ?

Comment: Check now n let me know

Comment: I have listed the options and the usage..you can try it out now @RaynD

Comment: @RaynD :  Here is another documentation for you - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

Comment: Not working either, can you please try it in your end. and let me know...

Comment: @Ryan - If you find something useful the do vote ..and if you get it done then do mark it as answer

Comment: You can go through documentation n try out few things.

Comment: Updated the command you should use. It did work for me ! If it doesn't work for you then you may have some other problem. All files were extracted for me in the same location itself. @RaynD

Comment: for me noting happen :(

Comment: You should keep trying and i guess you have different issue.